# Trimming and Removing text from string?

Tags: c#, string, trim

I want to trim a string and remove all the words that occur after a certain word.

**For example** - If the string contains 'very' text

```
string mySentence="  Today is very nice day!   ";

if (mysentence.Contains(very))
{
//remove everything that starts with 'very' until rest of the line..
}
```

***result should be:***

Today is

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
    string mySentence = "  Today is very   nice day!   ";

    if (mySentence.Contains("very"))
    {
        mySentence = mySentence.Remove(mySentence.IndexOf("very")).Trim();
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

First you split using the required word

```
string[] splits = mysentence.Split("very");
```

Since you've already made certain that "very" is inside the string, this will get you two strings. You want the first one (the split before the "very"). You need to trim the extra space from that one so:

```
string result = splits[0].Trim();
```

Comment: I know he said that the string contains the term 'very', but it is always a good code practice, to check if the string contains the term.

Comment: does this give this result :  Today is

Comment: @Somya - The OP is already checking for the existence of "very"

Comment: @user2760129 - Have you tried it?